# Parse String to datetime in 12 hour format in c#

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, datetime-format

How to convert date from one form to another? I have a string variable `bid="3/11/2014 10:57:00 PM"`. Where 3=month,11=day,2014=year,10=hour in 12 hour format, 57=minute,00=seconds PM=AM/PM format.

I need to convert variable bid into this date format and store it in a date variable. Bid has to be converted in this format: `"11/3/2014 10:57:00 PM"` where 11=day,3=month,2014=year 10=hour in 12 hour format,57=minute,00=seconds,PM=AM/PM format.

I tried `Datetime.parse` exact, with several combinations of strings but not worked. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Yeah. Try DateTime.ParseExact and start debugging your issues or give us an example what you tried. "Several combinations" smells like "without reading the documentation, and using any time debugging".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I need to convert variable bid into this date format and store it in a date variable

This works for me:

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("3/11/2014 10:57:00 PM", 
                             "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

> Bid has to be converted in this format: `"11/3/2014 10:57:00 PM"` where 11=day,3=month,2014=year 10=hour in 12 hour format,57=minute,00=seconds,PM=AM/PM format.

Well, you *could* convert it back to a stirng:

```
var s = dt.ToString("d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt");
```

but why do you need it in that format?  If you're sending it to a database then just leave it as a date - the database will then not have to worry about the date being in a specific format.  If you're displaying it in an app then either use the user's culture or define the format in the UI layer.